# tcolorbox with breakable change color to white using xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, color, tcolorbox, break-box

Using tcolorbox with xelatex, the font color is changed to white after the box when the box is broken.
Minimal exemple :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtcolorbox{test}{breakable} 
\begin{document}
\begin{test}
    \lipsum
\end{test}
This is written in white.
\end{document}
```

With pdflatex the last line is shown, not with xelatex.

Comment: it is probably a side effect of the changes preserve colors in such boxes with pdflatex/lualatex, https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/110.  As a work around you can set `\normalcolor\lipsum`, and better make a bug report.

Comment: I don't understand the OP problem. [Here is my TeX output](https://i.imgur.com/iqSV3gM.png)

Comment: I think this bug was already solved in recent versions. I've tested with `tcolorbox v4.31` and it works.

Comment: @UlrikeFisher It's not the same problem : text is black in both boxes. It turns white after the last part of the box : it's "This is written in white." which is white.

Comment: @Ignasi OK I checked with versions 4.32 and 4.40 and it's not working. With 4.31 it's ok, thanks !

Comment: @ib86 Then, as Ulrike Fischer suggested, I think you should fill a bug report.

Comment: @Ignasi. OK. I filled a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, xelatex does not support color stacks which are used since `tcolorbox v4.32` for breakable boxes. The implementation changed at several places and introduced this new error for xelatex.

I tried some hacks I used before. It seems that it is enough to reset the current color with `\color{.}` at the end of all things.

The following works for me:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\tcb@finalize@environment{%
  \color{.}% hack for xelatex
  \tcb@layer@dec%
}
\makeatother

\newtcolorbox{test}{breakable,colupper=blue}
\begin{document}
\begin{test}
\lipsum
\end{test}
This is written (not any longer) in white.
\end{document}
```